# differentiation an integration

Tags: calculus

Let $x,y$ and $r,\theta$ in Cartesian and polar cordinate. So
$$x=r\cos\theta  ,  y=r\sin \theta$$
Therefor $dx=\cos \theta dr-r\sin\theta d\theta $ and $dy=\sin \theta dr+r\cos \theta d\theta$. Therefore $$dA=dxdy=r\cos2\theta drd\theta+\sin2\theta/2(dr)^2-r^2\sin(2\theta)/2(d\theta)^2$$
My question is: with this $dA$ (elemant of surface) is it possible to find area of a shape for example a circle? I mean if it is possible to integrate what is the bound of integral?

Comment: The circle , in it parametric form , has equations $x=r \cos \theta, \;\; y =r \sin \theta$. Now the area of the circle is :

$${\rm E}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}x(\theta)y'(\theta)\,{\rm d}\theta$$

So, yes you can find it by using the polar coordinates of the circle. You can do the same for an ellipse.

Comment: Oups... sorry I forget about the other question. As Dr. MV said you cannot. Only by the way I mentioned above you can.

Comment: [Polar coordinate system - Integral calculus (area) - Generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Generalization)

Comment: Here is a decent tutorial on change of change of variables for multi-dimensional integration. https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m13w12/notes/class12.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation is actually wrong, but in a way that is sufficiently subtle that it is hard to explain without appealing to "this is small". The best way to understand this is in terms of the cross product:

The basic reason is that the area you are considering is the area of a parallelogram (that happens to be a square since the vectors are orthogonal). The area of a parallelogram with sides given by two vectors $a,b$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is
$$ a \times b \quad (= a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1), $$
the cross product of $a$ and $b$. Hence the standard area element is $dx \times dy = 1 \, dx \, dy$, (which is a entirely standard abuse of notation). What you are doing is changing basis of this space, and looking at a different parallelogram.

To see this, you can look at the simpler transformation $x=u$, $y=u+v$. Then you find $dx=du$ and $dy = du+dv$, so $dx \times dy = du \times (du+dv) = du \times du + du \times dv = du \times dv = 1 \, du \, dv$, because the cross product of parallel vectors is zero.

(Another question: how do you propose to compute $\int (dr)^2$?)

For your example, you have
$$ dx \times dy = (\cos{\theta} \, dr -r \sin{\theta} \, d\theta) \times (\sin{\theta} \, dr + r\cos{\theta} \, d\theta) \\
= (\text{stuff})(dr \times dr+ d\theta \times d\theta) -r \sin^{2}{\theta} \, d\theta \times dr + r \cos^2{\theta} dr \times d\theta \\
= r (\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}) \, dr \times d\theta \\
= r \, dr \,  d\theta,
$$
since $dr \times d\theta = -d\theta \times dr$.

---

(By the way, I did this with the cross product because you were more likely to be familiar with it, but as Alex M. remarks, the generalisation to more than 3 dimensions is done with the exterior product, which does similar things, like antisymmetry, to the cross product, but in more generality (for example, $a$, $a \wedge b$ and $a \wedge b \wedge c$ are different sorts of objects (a vector, bivector and trivector, respectively, whereas $a \times b$ is again a vector (well, nearly - it's actually a pseudovector))). For more information on this there are some quite basic books on differential forms ([this one](http://www.physics.oregonstate.edu/coursewikis/GDF/) is free on the internet, I've read another one with the same title, and it looks like there are a few others about). A more usual treatment is covered in courses on vector calculus (which in the UK is done in first year at university), where the thing is run through in terms of some sort of argument involving small parallelograms and vectors directly, and any "Methods in Mathematical Physics" text will cover this approach.

Really the hard step to justify is the $dx \wedge dy \to \, dx \, dy$ one: basically, the double integral operator
$$ \iint_A dx \wedge dy $$
is turned into an iterated integral,
$$ \int_a^b \left( \int_{c(y)}^{d(y)} \, dx \right) \, dy. $$

Comment: Chappers@ very nice. Only why $dr$ and $d\theta $ are perpendicular?

Comment: $r^2 = x^2+y^2$, so $2r \, dr = 2x \, dx + 2y \, dy$, whereas $\theta = \arctan{(x/y)}$, so $d\theta = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx - \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy$. Then obviously $dx \cdot dy = 0$, so $ dr \cdot d\theta = \dotsb = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} = 0 $, using the previous formula.

Comment: So many thanks Chappers

Answer (score 0):

You're calculation is off. What you need is the change of variables formula.

dA = dxdy = |D( T (x, y ) )|drd$\theta$

where T (x, y) = (rcos$\theta$, rsin$\theta$)

Essentially, dA = volume of infinitesimal parallelepiped in (r, $\theta$) coordinates. Which, is given by the determinant of the change of basis matrix.

In order to find the area of a circle, you're limits of integration over dA are from $\theta$ = 0 to $\theta$ = 2 $\pi$ and r=0 to r=R.

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx

Comment: Ragnar@ I understand your arguement. But why my calculation is not correct?

Comment: For starters, by change of variables, dA = rdrd$\theta$. Your expression evaluates to dA = rcos(2$\theta$) drd$\theta$ since only first order differentials matter here. You want the area of a very small parallelogram. Your expression cuts off part of its area.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your computation of $\mathbb{d}A$ is not correct is that $\mathbb{d}x \mathbb{d}y$ is not a product like the usual one, but one that obeys slightly different rules; it is called "exterior product", it is denoted by a wedge and it obeys the following rules: $\mathbb{d}x \wedge \mathbb{d}x = \mathbb{d}y \wedge \mathbb{d}y = 0$ and $\mathbb{d}x \wedge \mathbb{d}y = - \mathbb{d}y \wedge \mathbb{d}x$. Try now to redo $\mathbb{d}A$ taking into account these rules and you'll get $2r \space \mathbb{d}r \wedge \mathbb{d}\theta$, which (for complicated reasons) is $r \space \mathbb{d}r \mathbb{d}\theta$ (the wedge and the $2$ are gone). If you're studying pure mathematics, then you'll learn this in differential geometry (or, possibly, in algebra, when discussing the tensor product and related concepts).

Comment: Alex@ thanks. Why we use this type of argument for double integral? I mean why this $dx \wedge dy$ is useful?

Comment: @maryam: If you want to answer someone in particular, place the "@" sign *before* the name, not after. To answer your question: if all you need to do is compute double integrals, you'll never need the exterior product (which will only complicate things at this level). On the other hand, if you want to study abstract $n$-dimensional spaces (called "differential manifolds"), then this is a fundamental operation on them, but it's a whole story that could not be told in a short comment. If you're a maths student, then you'll learn about it later on.